# How to set start and end frames for a Lottie animation in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, lottie

How can you set the start and end frames programmatically?

```
playAnimation(int,int)
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer valid for Lottie until version 6.1.0. Newer versions might behave differently)

Unfortunately, Lottie for Android does not have different versions of `playAnimation` like the iOS version does.

To achieve what you want, you can call the following on the `LottieAnimationView`:

```kotlin
setMinAndMaxFrame(int, int)
playAnimation()
```

There are multiple versions of [setMinAndMaxFrame](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieAnimationView.java#L769) and there’s also similar versions for *progress* instead of frames which can be used instead.

If you do not want the animation to repeat the min and max frame over and over, you can call `repeatCount = 0` (or `setRepeatCount(0)` in Java)